# wxpython dynamically referring to widgets (wxformbuilder)

Tags: python, dynamic, wxpython, wxformbuilder

I often find myself in a situation where I want to create a number of `wx.StaticText`or some other widget in wxFormbuilder and be able to refer to these dynamically. Say i have a number of statictexts named `a0` through `a10`

How would I go about finding them in code?

One way is to do a list with all the variables in, but it is ugly, and feels inefficient? Maybe not but atleast the code gets cluttered with long lists everywhere.

```
 def updateLabels(self, data):
     guiLabels = [self.a0, self.a1, self.a2 ..... ]
     for i in range(len(guiLabels)):
         guiLabels[i].SetLabel(data[i)
```

How do you go about fixing this?

Another alternative is to make the guiLabels list when initiating the app. However, I've had some problems with finding them. you have to call GetChildren() on the top window and set a different `wx.ID` for every `StaticText` and then go through every element and find this ID you made.. And the formatting when I do this is really off key.. The text gets different background colors and doesnt respect it's alignments and other funky stuff.

Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this could work for you:

```
for x in xrange(10):
    name = "a%s" % x # dynamically generating reference names
    obj = getattr(self, name) # getting the object reference from the parent object
    obj.SetLabel("xyz")
```

Comment: Answers on SO should be more complete than this. At the very least you need to explain, what has been done to solve the problem, and why. An answer containing *"maybe"* is a strong indication, that you don't know the answer. In that case, don't post it as one.

Comment: My answer does answer the question. The code is trivial and self explanatory. The word maybe was conversational and not indicative of not knowing the answer.

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality. While reviewing I came to the same conclusion, and pointed out specific points that could be improved.